# Using parfor with options to parallelize code

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have the following MATLAB code:

```
n_part = 5; %count the participants
options.params.cutoff=1;
options.params.lags=0;% use zero, to set n=0 as in eq 4 in the paper, otherwise you will include historical values in the model (one connectivity matrix per historical value) 
options.params.autocorrelation=0; % to exclude self dependancies, since we have already take care of this. This makes the diagonal values equal to zero in the model
options.params.concurrent=1; % must be one to include the concurrent information
options.params.pass_th=0;
options.perc=[0.7 0.3]; % First argument is the partition size to calculate SV, second argument is the size of the test sample
options.rep_svd=10; % how many times to repeat the svd decomposition to maximize out of sample data predictions
options.rep_model=1; % if number of frames not empty, how many times recalculate the model based on the minimum required frames

parfor i=1:n_part
    display(['Running participant ' num2str(i)])
    options.min_frames=size(signal,1); %how many frames to include in the model
    options.SV=SV; %assign SV to options
end
```

I want to optimize the `for` loop, since each iteration is independent.  So, first, I tried this:

```
parfor i=1:n_part
    .
    .
    .
end
```

That gave me this error:

```
Error: The variable options in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
parfor i=1:n_part
```

I then tried this:

```
parpool(2);
parfor i=1:n_part
    display(['Running participant ' num2str(i)])
    y=TC{i};
    TC_no_AC_LS{i}=remove_autocorrelation(y,n_ar);
    
    frameSV(i).signal=TC_no_AC_LS{i}; % pick the signal with no autocorrelation
    [SV, R]=model_tsvd(signal,options); %calculate the SVD
    
    frameSV(i).min_frames = size(frameSV(i).signal, 1);
    frameSV(i).SV = SV;
end

for i = 1 : n_part
    options.min_frames= frameSV(i).min_frames; %how many frames to include in the model
    options.SV = frameSV(i).SV; %assign SV to options
    signal = frameSV(i).signal;
    m(:,:,i) = make_model_tsvd(signal, options); % calculate the model
end
```

But got this error:

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...
Connected to the parallel pool (number of workers: 2).
Error using connectotyping_example2>(parfor supply)
Undefined function 'frameSV' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in connectotyping_example2 (line 27)
parfor i=1:n_part
```

Is there a way to fix this, so the iterations of the loop can run in parallel?

Comment: On which line does it throw that error? Could you please post a [mcve], i.e. code that **we** can run? You appear to be using cells which are nested in cells and/or growing arrays in a loop. The former might be a problem for `parfor`, the latter certainly is. You might want to check out `spmd` as well, which is easier in some cases.

Comment: It occurs on the `parfor i=1:n_part` line.

Comment: I made a short, stand-alone example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the following two lines:

```
options.min_frames=size(signal,1); %how many frames to include in the model
options.SV=SV; %assign SV to options
```

Parfor loops must ensure that each loop iteration is independent of the next. In your code above, it looks like `options` is updated on each iteration, and the updated struct is then used on the next iteration. This cannot be done using parfor, since there is *technically* no guarantee that iteraion *i* and *i+1* will be done on the same machine.

If `min_frames` and `SV` are not required to be a part of the options struct, you could store their value on each iteration in a data-independent way:

```
parfor i=1:n_part
    % ...
    frameSV(i).min_frames = size(signal,1);
    frameSV(i).SV = SV;
end
% Do some calculation with frameSV to get the data you need, after the loop
```

This will create a `1 x n_part` struct array where the values of `min_frames` and `SV` from each loop iteration are stored independently.

Again, this is all assuming that the value of `options` does not *need* to be updated on one iteration and used on the next.

Comment: How is `frameSV` declared and where is it declared?

Comment: Created in the loop and exists after the loop. For example, in the command window try typing: `>> someVar(1).SV = 1` and it will create a variable `someVar` with field SV. The next iteration `someVar(2).SV = 2` adds a second element to the struct array.

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion as I understood it.  I got past the original error, but am still getting an error.  I updated the question with that code and error message.

Comment: Small note: you can't "grow" arrays within a `parfor` loop, i.e. you need to initialise the struct `frameSV` to its proper size.